# How to get values from Map where Object is a list of key pairs?

Tags: java, yaml

I have been searching for hours trying to find how to read in this yaml file where app is a directory of key/values.  But I can't find anyway to access the app list of pairs.  I tried to first get the "app" value with get and then do a second get to  the the value for "buildRpmPath" but the compile says no.  I can see the Object is a LinkedHashMap but I can't do anything with it.   How do you code this?

Yaml input file:

```
# Servlet MCD configuration file
app:
  buildRpmPath: /home/jkerich/Software/buildrpm/
  rootConfigurationPath: /home/jkerich/Software/RTConfigurationFiles/`
```

Java code that is trying to get buildRpmPath value.

```
inputStream = new FileInputStream(defaultPath);
                
Map<String, Object> yamlMaps = yaml.load(inputStream);
System.out.println(yamlMaps);
{app={buildRpmPath=/home/jkerich/Software/buildrpm/, rootConfigurationPath=/home/jkerich/Software/RTConfigurationFiles/}}

buildRpmPath = yamlMaps.get("app").get("buildRpmPath").toString();`
```

I have search on Map and LinkedHashMap and found nothing on how to get into the pair list.  I have tried casting, loading Object into Map or LinkedHashMap but again the compiler says no.  I have looked for a way to set Map with the Object returning a as a String.  Nothing I can think of works.  I just can't access/convert the Object into a Map.  I can see them in the debugger, but there is are methods that seem to work.

Comment: _"but the compile says no"_ - Compilers don't say "no".  [Edit] your question and include the complete error message or stack trace.

Comment: And show how you tried casting.

Comment: `buildRpmPath = ((Map)yamlMaps.get("app")).get("buildRpmPath").toString();` would seem more promising

Answer (score 0):

I have switched to jackson-dataformat-yaml and by building classes to hold the fields was able to finally read in the yaml file based on the https://www.w3schools.io/file/yaml-java-read-write/ YAML Tutorials.

The one thing the tutorial did not make clear is the YAMLFactory is calling the classes setters which was based on the key name (i.e. app: is setApp()) and I was trying to use the setAppconfig for the AppConfig.java vs. setDatabase (for DatabaseConfig.java) when I started to modify their example causing a not found exception.